# How to find Index by Alias in Elasticsearch java api?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Reindexing takes 30 seconds and I don't want my search to be offline for 30 seconds every time I need to reindex. I'm trying to do this:

1. Find old index with alias = abc123
2. Create new index and fill with new data
3. Remove alias and delete old index
4. Give new index alias = abc123

I can't seem to find any java code that does 1). Everything else is fine. Anyone? or is there another way that is better?

Using Elasticsearch 0.90.9.

Comment: Are you using any admin plugin? Like elasticsearch-head, elasticsearch-hq

Comment: No. Just using the basic TransportClient()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this to get all of the aliases:

```
 client.admin().cluster()
    .prepareState().execute()
    .actionGet().getState()
    .getMetaData().getAliases();
```

This returns a map with the index name as the `key` and the `aliases` as the value. So you can iterate over the map to get the index name.

Comment: Actually, it seems to return a map in this format: alias => [ index_name => meta data, ... ]

Answer (score 18):

Here is the method for your reference for finding all indices in a given aliasName:

```
public Set<String> getIndicesFromAliasName(String aliasName) {

    IndicesAdminClient iac = client.admin().indices();
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, List<AliasMetaData>> map = iac.getAliases(new GetAliasesRequest(aliasName))
            .actionGet().getAliases();

    final Set<String> allIndices = new HashSet<>();
    map.keysIt().forEachRemaining(allIndices::add);
    return allIndices;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

a better solution would be , the map will have indexes as keys

```
GetAliasesResponse var = client.admin().indices().getAliases(new GetAliasesResponse var = client.admin().indices().getAliases(new GetAliasesRequest("merged")).actionGet();
ImmutableOpenMap<String, List<AliasMetaData>> v1 = var.getAliases();
```

Comment: I agree. Instead of getting the entire cluster's metadata, this is a better request

Answer (score 4):

With the latest API the accepted answer no longer works. Similar solution using latest client (5.2.0):

```
SortedMap<String, AliasOrIndex> lookup = esClient.admin().cluster()
    .prepareState().execute()
    .actionGet().getState()
    .getMetaData().getAliasAndIndexLookup();
if (lookup.containsKey(ALIAS_NAME)) {
    lookup.get(ALIAS_NAME).getIndices().get(0).getIndex().getName();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Aliases API like this:
`esClient.admin().indices().prepareGetAliases(ALIAS_NAME).get().getAliases();`

Key of the resulting map is the index name that given alias maps to.

Answer (score 2):

```
private String getIndexNameFromAliasName(final String aliasName) {
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, AliasMetaData> indexToAliasesMap = client.admin().cluster()
            .state(Requests.clusterStateRequest())
            .actionGet()
            .getState()
            .getMetaData()
            .aliases().get(aliasName);
    if(indexToAliasesMap != null && !indexToAliasesMap.isEmpty()){
        return indexToAliasesMap.keys().iterator().next().value;
    }
    return null;
}
```