# How do I find the alias for an index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to find out the alias for a given index in ElasticSearch. Basically, the reverse of this question: [How to find Index by Alias in Elasticsearch java api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349947/how-to-find-index-by-alias-in-elasticsearch-java-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it.

```
// Get the map of [alias => [index => metadata, ...], ...]
ImmutableOpenMap<String, ImmutableOpenMap<String, AliasMetaData>> aliasesAndIndices = 
        client.admin().cluster()
        .prepareState().execute().actionGet().getState()
        .getMetaData().getAliases();
Map<String, String> aliasForIndex = new HashMap<>();

// Convert it to a map of [index => alias, ...]
for (String alias : aliasesAndIndices.keys().toArray(String.class)) {
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, AliasMetaData> innerMap = aliasesAndIndices.get(alias);
    for (String index : innerMap.keys().toArray(String.class)) {
        aliasForIndex.put(index, alias);
    }
}
```

And then I could get the alias for an index like this.

```
aliasForIndex.get(index)
```